# How Scraping Dynamic Variable Javascript value using BeautifulSoup and Requests

Tags: javascript, python, beautifulsoup

I am scraping login page, i only need VAR SALT= variable in JAVASCRIPT TAG.
This is the website = https://ib.muamalatbank.com/ib-app/loginpage

When i am read all answer here,using BeautifulSoup and requests, i can get these 2 variable(Maybe because its static):
***var muserid='User ID must be filled';
var mpassword= 'Password must be filled';***

But when i try Scrape this var SALT= , its give me all VAR value.
[My result code in python](https://i.stack.imgur.com/36cHR.jpg)

I just need This VAR SALT value only with no Quotation mark
Here the PIC = [Source VAR SALT VALUE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/05fde.jpg)

I already using re.search, and re.compile, re.findall, but i am Newbie, keep gives me error "Object cannot string...."

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests
import re
import lxml
import json

URL = 'https://ib.muamalatbank.com/ib-app/loginpage'
REF = 'https://ib.muamalatbank.com'

HEADERS = {'User-Agent': 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:81.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/81.0', 'origin': URL, 'referer': REF}

s = requests.session()
soup = bs(s.get(URL, headers=HEADERS, timeout=5, verify=False).text,"html.parser")

script = soup.find_all("script")[11]
ambilteks = soup.find_all(text=re.compile("salt=(.*?)"))
print(ambilteks)
```

Note: 1) i need Help but not interested using Selenium,

1. I have script in PHP-Laravel, its fully working(i need in Python), but i have no knowledge in laravel, anyone can ask me , i will give the Laravel code

Please help me, thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Try using re.compile and add the `''` into your regex, then extract first result. Not tested with page response. First verify the string is actually present in the response.

```
p = re.compile(r"var salt='(.*?)'")
res = p.findall(s.get(URL, headers=HEADERS, timeout=5, verify=False).text)[0]
print(res)
```

Comment: Not work Brother. Can you give me full code? thanks

Comment: what does happen?